# How to call objects that uses sap.ui.require sentence

Tags: sapui5

I've been checking last openui5 documentation and I saw that there is a "new way" of creating classes.

So now, using sap.ui.define we can create classes in a AMD way like the following -

```
sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/ui/base/Object'],
    function(jQuery, Object) {
        "use strict";

    var foo = Object.extend("Foo", {
        metadata : {
            properties : {}
        }
    });

    foo.prototype.someFunction = function(){};

    return foo;
},true);
```

The thing is that I'm not sure how to call this kind of classes from controllers. I would like to use AMD syntax in the control, but I haven't found any example -

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

        sap.ui.controller('settings.mvc.controller.App', {

            onInit: function() {
                 //Foo is always undefined
            },
        });

})();
```

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I would like to avoid that kind of sentence, and make it more in the AMD way, using sap.ui.define([dependencies]., function(dependencies){ //control definition })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `sap.ui.require()`:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2488
(note the difference to `jQuery.sap.require()`!)

This function is new and not yet available in the current stable release 1.26, but as soon as the next beta preview is out (or when you build UI5 on your own), you can write something like:

`sap.ui.require(['Foo'], function(Foo) {
    Foo.someFunction();
});`

This is the symmetric counterpart to sap.ui.define() and works asynchronously, so I guess it is what you are looking for.

(I assume your question is about loading Foo from a different file, because when written within one file, it is already defined:
http://jsbin.com/lagiviyoja/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Gotta love how UI5 is constantly evolving at such a great pace!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about. The thing is that I'm not sure how to create a controller using the sap.ui.require. Do you think it is possible to do it ?